# Prove that $T = I$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**. *Suppose that $T^2 = I$ and suppose that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of T. Prove that $T=I$.* $\DeclareMathOperator{null}{Null}$

---

My attempt:

Suppose $v \in V$, and consider the vector $Tv-v$. If $Tv-v$ is an eigenvector, then

\begin{align}
T(Tv-v)&=\lambda(Tv-v) \\ 
T^2v-Tv &= \\ 
Iv-Tv &=\\
v-Tv &=\\
-Tv+v &=\\
-1(Tv-v) &=
\end{align}
so $\lambda = -1$. This is a contradiction to our assumption since $-1$ is not an eigenvalue. Thus, 
\begin{align}
\lambda &= 1 \\
&=1(Tv-v).
\end{align}
Now the eigenspace of $T$ is 
\begin{align}
\null(T-\lambda I) &=\null(T-I) \\ 
T-I &= 0 \\
T&=I
\end{align}

Am I correct with my definitions and assumptions?

Comment: The equation $-1(Tv-v)=\lambda(Tv-v)$ seems to be tricky...

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $T$ is a divisor of $x^2-1$, so it has distinct roots. Hence $T$ is diagonalizable. Since the only eigenvalue is $1$, $T$ is similar to $I$; therefore $T=I$.

Comment: It's true that if $Tv-v$ is an eigenvector of $T,$ say with eigenvalue $\lambda,$ then $$-(Tv-v)=\lambda(Tv-v).$$ From this, though, you cannot conclude that $\lambda=-1$ *unless you know that* $Tv-v$ is not the zero vector. Do you see why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make any sense of your solution, sorry.

**Hint:** $T^2=I$ says $(T-I)(T+I)=0$. Now saying $-1$ is not an eigenvalue means _____. Hence _____, so $T-I=0$.

(Hint regarding the hint: The *definition* of "$-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$" has nothing to do with determinants. Look back - the *definition* was what?)

Comment: means $\lambda = -1$ is not in the eigenspace of T but $\lambda = 1$ is. Hence $null(T-1I)=0$?

Comment: No, that's not the definition. The definition is in the book the very first time eigenvalues were mentioned. (You could also get a solution from the fact that the nullspace of $T-I=0$, but that involves using some stuff - starting from the _definition_ makes this problem much easier.)

Comment: The definition looks like this: "$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $T-\lambda I$ is..."

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $(T-\lambda I)v = 0$

Comment: Almost. You left out the words "... for some non-zero $v$'. Whatever. It's a fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible.

Comment: Would you be able to finish your proof? I would really appreciate it

Comment: I've already given you 99.99 percent of the proof. This is obviously a homework question - you should do _some_ of it yourself. (Also Henning has given you a more or less complete solution - really the same as mine, although it looks very different.)

Comment: Nope not a homework question, I have an exam tomorrow and I am trying to understand this question. I want to understand it, not just have a solution

Comment: That had better be the truth. Saying that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$ says exactly that $T+I$ is _invertible_. And we know that $(T-I)(T+I)=0$. So $T-I=(T-I)[(T+I)(T+I)^{-1}] =[(T-I)(T+I)](T+I)^{-1}= 0(T+I)^{-1}=0$.

Comment: @David: It is not quite the same -- yours is elegant and slicker in the case where $V$ is finite-dimensional (which is not promised explicitly in the question), but doesn't generalize as easily to the infinite-dimensional case where $T-\lambda I$ might be injective without being invertible. Then we'd have to start talking about one-sided inverses instead, and write $(T+I)(T-I)$ instead of $(T-I)(T+I)$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have a bad tendency to read "eigenvalue" as "element of the spectrum". Bad.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit roundabout to divide according to whether $Tv-v$ is an eigenvector.

Instead I would just say that $T(Tv-v) = v-Tv = -(Tv-v)$ (due to the computation you're already showing), so if $Tv-v$ were nonzero it would be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. We're told there is no such thing, so $Tv-v=0$, or in other words $Tv=v$ for all $v$.